# differentiate local storage for two domains under same IP

Tags: html

I am using local storage concept for my website. I am using two different URLs like xyz.com/production and xyz.com/testing. Is there any way to clear individual local storage data like "xyz.com/production" and "xyz.com/testing" separately.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to combine your variables in an array for each "individual storage" you want to have? I think in that way you can have an array of variables named "productionVariables" and another one named "testingVariables" and clear them individualy.